# Mapping an object of array in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object  each key of the object has an array value

```
const correctionsWords  = {
"word": [ "1" , "2"] ,
"word2": ["20" ,"22" ] 
};
```

I did map through each key by using the following code

```
let correctionList =  Object.keys(correctionsWords).map(  (key)  => {
        return (
          <div>
              {
                  //console.log( 'After Mapping ' , correctionsWords[key]) [1,2,3]
                   <ul>
                     <li>{key} { /* word  */}
                      <ul> 
                        <li>{correctionsWords[key]}</li>
                      </ul>
                     </li>  
                     </ul>
              } 
          </div> 
        ); });
```

the result is * key: word 
                    * value: 1 2 
How can I  list the values of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map again each array element:

```
<ul>
  {correctionsWords[key].map(el => (
    <li key={el}>{el}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

I've used a `key` as the element here. If the elements are not unique better use another key. Also, you need another key for your object mapping in the topmost `div`:

```
return (
    <div key={key}>
    ...
```

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer helped you consider accepting it, please.

Comment: Sure  It did help me

Comment: @RamiSalim Look at the up and down arrow, there is a checkmark, press it.

Comment: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you’re looking for is to replace that innermost `li` with:

```
{
  correctionsWords[key].map(value => <li>{value}</li>)
}
```